# Access datatable in parentform from childform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

I have a parentform (let's call it frmParent) that contains a datagridview. The datagridview is populated from a datatable. The data in the datatable comes from an Excel file.

When a button is pressed, the childform (let's call it frmChild) is loaded in a panel.

Therefore I have the following code:

```
Private Sub OpenChildForm(childForm As Form, btnSender As Object)
    If activeForm IsNot Nothing Then activeForm.Close()
    ActivateButton(btnSender)
    activeForm = childForm
    childForm.TopLevel = False
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.panelDesktopPanel.Controls.Add(childForm)
    Me.panelDesktopPanel.Tag = childForm
    childForm.BringToFront()
    childForm.Show()
    lblTitle.Text = UCase(childForm.Text)
End Sub
```

In the childform I have several text- and checkboxes. I would like to populate the text- and checkboxes with data from the datatable in the parent form.

I can't access the datatable from the childform with the following code:

```
Dim TableRow() As DataRow = frmParent.ds.Tables("TableName").Select("F1=5")
```

What I would like to know if it's possible to access the datatable in the parentform from the childform or do I have to "copy" the datatable from the parentform to the childform.
The data keeps the same, so the datatable stays the same.

Kind regards,

Björn

Comment: (Why are you using a dumbed down Form instead of a UserControl?) You just need to pass the DataTable's reference (or, better, a BindingSource linked to the DataTable) to your Form/UserControl. You can use a Public Property or Method or a dedicated Constructor (e.g., `Sub New(dt As DataTable)`)

Comment: Thnx @Jimi, that's what i was looking for.